# Express Session: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using ExpressJS and have been trying to get PassportJS working. In my `express.js` config, I have the following:

```
app.configure(function () {
        // dynamic helpers
        app.use(helpers(config.app.name));

        // cookieParser should be above session
        app.use(express.cookieParser());

        // bodyParser should be above methodOverride
        app.use(express.bodyParser());
        app.use(express.methodOverride());

        // express/mongo session storage
        app.use(express.session({
          secret: 'noobjs',
          store: new mongoStore({
            url: config.db,
            collection : 'sessions'
          })
        }));

        // connect flash for flash messages
        app.use(flash());

        // use passport session
        app.use(passport.initialize());
        app.use(passport.session());

...
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error when I run the app:-

```
store.on('disconnect', function(){ storeReady = false; });
^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'
```

I think it has something to do with initialization order, but am too inexperienced around express to know what the order should be.

Can anyone offer some direction please?

Answer (score 1):

`npm` bit me on the arse. I brought down the wrong package. Problem solved.

For reference, the correct package for this is `npm install connect-mongo`.